# Bash Script have issue

Tags: bash

I would like to write small script in bash.

Request: I have one WAS application is running on one server.It is containing many jvms which are running.

Now I would like to write a script for what are all jvms running and what are all the stopping the jvms and store it in one txt file.

I already written some script as below.

But when I am running some of the jvms status unable to show in the txt file.

Could you please help me?

```
if [ -n  `grep TNT_Stg_AppSrv01  /tmp/Rajesh/log.txt ` ]; then

    echo "TNT_Stg_AppSrv01  status UP <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"> " >> /tmp/Rajesh/ServerStartStatus.html

  else

    echo "TNT_Stg_AppSrv01  is stopped <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"> " > /tmp/Rajesh/ServerStopStatus.html
fi



if [ -n  `grep jvm3  /tmp/Rajesh/log.txt ` ]; then

    echo "jvm3 status is UP <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"> " >> /tmp/Rajesh/ServerStartStatus.html

  else

    echo "jvm3  is stopped <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"> " >> /tmp/Rajesh/ServerStopStatus.html
fi

if [ -n `grep jvm1  /tmp/Rajesh/log.txt ` ]; then

    echo "jvm1 status is UP <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"> " >> /tmp/Rajesh/ServerStartStatus.html

  else

    echo "jvm1  is stopped <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"> " > /tmp/Rajesh/ServerStopStatus.html
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

if e.g. this portion of the first line:

```
 grep TNT_Stg_AppSrv01  /tmp/Rajesh/log.txt
```

prints NOTHING, as is the case when grep doesn't find the search string, then you will EFFECTIVELY have

```
if [ -n  ]; then
```

... on the first line in your script - AS IT IS RUNNING.

Put `"` for ends of the string you're checking in the `if` - always.

e.g.

```
if [ -n  "`grep TNT_Stg_AppSrv01  /tmp/Rajesh/log.txt`" ]; then
```

... is likely to not work a bit better.

I'd also suggest to use `$( command )` instead of the back-ticks.
I believe it is more portable - and also a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `-n` in your conditionals, which checks the length of the string (in this case the output from your grep command).

You'd be better off using the return code, which is the default behavior for `if`, i.e.:

```
if [ grep TNT_Stg_AppSrv01  /tmp/Rajesh/log.txt ]; then   
    echo "TNT_Stg_AppSrv01  status UP <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"> " >> /tmp/Rajesh/ServerStartStatus.html    
  else    
    echo "TNT_Stg_AppSrv01  is stopped <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"> " > /tmp/Rajesh/ServerStopStatus.html
fi
```

From grep's man page:

> The exit status is 0 if selected lines are found, and 1 if not found.  If an error occurred the exit status is 2.  (Note: POSIX error handling code should check for '2' or greater.)

Comment: `grep >/dev/null` maybe ;-)

Comment: I have tried as you given above command,however TNT_Stg AppSrv01 is not comming in output ,i mean it is not displaying neither start status nor stop status. currentlt the jvm is running status.

Comment: You have mixed use of `>` and `>>`.  I guessed that was intentional, but if jvm1 is stopped, you're going to overwrite ServerStopStatus.html.

Comment: If iam using ">" for both conditions i am not getting printed stopstatus.html even though TNT_Stg AppSrv01 stopped.Any command for this

Comment: `>` will create a new file, `>>` will append.  Switch everything to `>>` and it should work.  I'd probably initialize the file in the very beginning, before any of the conditionals, so I'd be starting with a known file.